# Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 18063885380364533825 bytes)

Tags: php, odbc, firebird, ubuntu-14.04, memory-limit

I am using `odbc_connect()` to connect a firebird database in a script hosted on Ubuntu 14.04

Query has to fetch only one row

```
$connect = odbc_connect("EXAMPLE", "GONE", "fishing");
$query = "SELECT REMITTONAME, REMITADDRESS, REMITCITY FROM PO WHERE NUM=10072";
$result = odbc_exec($connect, $query);
```

Error occurs on line#3 where I call odbc_exec($connect, $query)

`Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 18063885380364533825 bytes)`

I am surprised why odbc_exec function is trying to allocate 15.66 exabyte?

My memory limit in php.ini is set to 128M, and I tried to increase it to 500M.

`memory_limit = 500M`

I also tried to put below at start of my script

`ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`

Searched everywhere on the internet but nothing solved my issue and still trying to figure out the cause.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

**NOTE:**

Non of the columns selected in query are null or empty

Comment: You might take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286589/linux-odbc-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size

Comment: @derp where is the solution?

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version (2.0.2.153), and otherwise file a bug at http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/ODBC

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am using firebird 2.5 with PHP 5.5.9

Comment: @MarkRotteveel bug reported http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/ODBC-175

Comment: With version I meant the ODBC driver version, not the Firebird server version

Answer (score 3):

You try to allocate

`1.80638854 × 10^13 megabytes` 500MB it not enough ;) i think you have a bug in your Query or the odbc module.

> In the 64bit version the odbc crashs when one of the return fields are NULL. So the work around is to replace all the null fields when retriving the query.
>
> `select ifnull(tluser,'') as USER from database.table`

This should help you with your problem. More information you can get here:

[Linux odbc Fatal error: Allowed memory size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286589/linux-odbc-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size)

Comment: ifnull is not a function of firebird database and I have already confirmed that all my columns are filled, non of them is null or empty

Comment: @TahirYasin The equivalent of `ifnull` for Firebird is [`COALESCE`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-intfunc-coalesce.html).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel but I can see non my queried columns are null or empty