# Zend Framework 1.12 + Crontab + odbc query - Fatal error: Allowed memory size

Tags: php, zend-framework, odbc, cron, ibm-midrange

currently I have a developed app at Zend Zend Framework 1.12 in a server Ubuntu 14.04.2 with iSeries Access ODBC Driver 64-bit

When I manually execute the following query from a controller, I correctly receive the result:

```
class MaestrosController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

public function indexAction() {    
    $this->_query("SELECT OKCUNO AS VALUE, OKCUNM AS OPTION FROM OCUSMA WHERE OKCONO = 1");
}

private function _query($query) {             
    try {
        $conexion = $this->_connect();
        $result = odbc_exec($conexion, $query);
    }catch (Exception $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
    $salida = array();
    while( ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) !== false ) {
        array_push($salida, $row);
    }
    $this->_disconect($conexion);
    return $salida;
}

private function _connect()
{
   $objConnect =  odbc_connect('EXPO', $this->odbc_user,$this->odbc_calve) or die('Connect: '.odbc_errormsg()."\n");
   return $objConnect;
}

private function _disconect($conexion)
{
   odbc_close($conexion);
}
}
```

However, when I execute it through contrab:

```
php /var/www/vhosts/core.lan/application/cronjobs/cronjob.php >> /tmp/logcron.log
```

cronjob.php

```
define("_CRONJOB_",true);
require_once('/var/www/vhosts/core.lan/httpdocs/index.php');

(...)

$this->_query("SELECT OKCUNO AS VALUE, OKCUNM AS OPTION FROM OCUSMA WHERE OKCONO = 1");

(...)
```

The following error message appears:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16815550472902410251 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/core.lan/application/models/DbTable/M3.php on line 259.
```

The line 259 corresponds to `$result = odbc_exec($conexion, $query);`

In order to execute through cron, my index has been configurated as follows:

```
(...)

$application->bootstrap();

//Cronjobs don't need all the extra's so we don't execute the bootstrap
if(!defined('_CRONJOB_') || _CRONJOB_ == false){
    $application->bootstrap()->run();
}
```

There is nothing else in the logs, none error message excepts the memory size.

---

Looking for a solution I’ve found out that if I execute the following query  through contrab:

```
SELECT OKCUNO AS VALUE, OKCUNM AS OPTION FROM OCUSMA WHERE OKCONO = 1 FETCH FIRST 14 ROWS ONLY
```

It perfectly Works:

```
+-----------+-------------------------------------+
| VALUE     | OPTION                              |
+-----------+-------------------------------------+
| 0000001   | ANIBAL                              |
| 0000002   | MODAS                               |
| 0000003   | NOVIAS                              |
| 0000004   | ROSA                                |
| 0000005   | RC                                  |
| 0000006   | BELLAESPOSA                         |
| 0000007   | RICARDO                             |
| 0000008   | YOLANDA                             |
| 0000009   | HUELVA .                            |
| 0000010   | DROP                                |
| 0000011   | DOBADOCA                            |
| 0000013   | MARIA                               |
| 0000014   | MODA                                |
| 0000015   | HABITUS                             |
+-----------+-------------------------------------+
```

nevertheless, if I execute the following one a fatal error appears:

```
SELECT OKCUNO AS VALUE, OKCUNM AS OPTION FROM OCUSMA WHERE OKCONO = 1 FETCH FIRST 15 ROWS ONLY
```

If I want to see that information is shown in that line I execute `isql -v EXPO` and I receive the following result

```
+-----------+-------------------------------------+
| VALUE     | OPTION                              |
+-----------+-------------------------------------+
| 0000001   | ANIBAL                              |
| 0000002   | MODAS                               |
| 0000003   | NOVIAS                              |
| 0000004   | ROSA                                |
| 0000005   | JON                                 |
| 0000006   | BELLAESPOSA                         |
| 0000007   | CHARLES                             |
| 0000008   | YOLANDA                             |
| 0000009   | HUELVA                              |
| 0000010   | DROP                                |
| 0000011   | DOBADOCA                            |
| 0000013   | MARIA                               |
| 0000014   | MODA                                |
| 0000015   | HABITUS                             |
| 0000016   | Mª ANGELES                          |
+-----------+-------------------------------------+
```

I deduce the problem could come from the character `ª`.

---

I’ve read the following article in the website IBM https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_61/rzatv/rzatvlanguageodbc.htm:

> **ODBC Application Character Set**
>
> The ODBC application character set is defined by the current locale's
>   character set.

`$ locale` return the following:

```
LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

But, the command `$ sudo /opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/bin64/cwbnltbl` gives me that:

```
cwbnltbl - Download conversion table utility
Usage: cwbnltbl source-code-page target-code-page [host] [uid] [pwd]
Linux locale codeset=UTF-8 ccsid=1208
```

and I do not know what to do with it.

The only information I could find and which is more or less similar than the problem I have is this post: [Linux odbc Fatal error: Allowed memory size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286589/linux-odbc-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size), however the solution proposed cannot help me at all.

I kindly ask somebody to give me some support in this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the locale of the environment where the php script is executed.

Running the following statement I could fix it:

```
LANG = es_ES;
```

If I run the following via crontab, I have no problems:

```
LANG = es_ES; php -f /var/www/vhosts/core.lan/application/cronjobs/cronjob.php >> /tmp/logcron.log
```

So the solution is to fix the php locale.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running in to [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014510046) problem with the old iSeries Access for Linux ODBC Driver. As the 64-bit ABI changed in unixODBC 2.2.13 to support 64-bit parameters, the iSeries Access 7.1 (and earlier) driver will produce incorrect results when used with applications built against unixODBC 2.2.13 or newer.

The solution is to use the new IBM i Access ODBC driver that's part of the [IBM i Access Client Solutions - Linux Application Package](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-ibmi-access-client-solutions-linux/), which has been updated to use the new ABI.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, i'll try updating the driver.

Comment: Hi Kevin, recently i've updated the unixODBC to 2.3.4 but the problem persist... ¿anything else I can try?

Comment: Did you update the driver? The problem is that you're using a driver that is too old for your version of unixODBC or, conversely, that your version of unixODBC is too new for your driver. Updating the version of unixODBC will not help you in this case - you need to either update the driver to the one in the ACS Application Package or downgrade unixODBC to something prior to 2.2.13.