# MS Access Database with ODBC driver IBM i Access Client

Tags: php, odbc

I want to connect to my MS Access Database (.mdb/.accdb files) via PHP (7.2.10), SLE 12.3. I started with libmdbodbc.so.1 driver which comes with package libmdbodbc1 0.7-3.1 (Source: mdbtools-0.7-3.1). With this I got an error "Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 140 Tbytes)" [Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498682/allowed-memory-size-exhausted-with-odbc-exec-libmdb-mdbtools?noredirect=1#comment93866582_53498682). So I got advised to use the new ODBC driver from the IBM i Access Client Solutions Linux Application Package [Stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42132558/odbc-prepare-gives-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-exhausted).

I installed ibm-iaccess-1.1.0.10-1.0.x86_64.rpm. But how to set an access database as source? Still tried "Driver={IBM i Access ODBC Driver 64-bit};Data Source=%s;System=localhost" (%s is replaced by path to .mdb/.accdb-File) and other parameters (System, Server, Servername, Database, ...), but always got an error and cannot establish connection to database or

```
"Communication link failure. comm rc=10061 - CWBCO1049 - The IBM i server application is not started, or the connection was blocked by a firewall"
```

But the database file is local, so there is no firewall. And when using libmdbodbc.so.1 I can connect to this database. I think I have to got the correct parameters to set the database file.

So how to setup configuration for MS Access Database file with ODBC driver IBM i Access Client?

Thank you for your response and best!

Comment: Have you already tried something similar to this? https://www.sitepoint.com/using-an-access-database-with-php/

Comment: Yes this is what I did first with libmdbodbc.so.1 driver (in this example they are working with Windows (DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)})). But this driver is not working correctly (see above), so I switched as advised to IBM driver.

Comment: now... the link does talk only about php_pdo_odbc.dll not libmdbodbc maybe there is something that i do not get ?

Comment: php_pdo_odbc.dll is the Windows library file, as I still wrote. I'm working with Linux.

Comment: Does anybody have an idea how to setup configuration for MS Access Database file with ODBC driver IBM i Access Client?