# Configuring PHP 7.4.7 with Informix Drivers

Tags: php, odbc, 64-bit, driver, informix

I'm working on migrating a windows based XAMPP server to the latest release, which uses a 64-bit architecture and PHP 7.4.7. Our previous version used a 32-bit architecture.

One of the required databases this server has to interact with is an informix database. Formerly, we used a 32-bit informix odbc driver to access this db via php odbc_connect. Now that we're moving to a 64-bit architecture, the 32-bit driver no longer works. We have a 64-bit informix driver as well, but it seems no matter which driver I use I get one of two errors:

Using the 32-bit driver produces: "The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application"

Using the 64-bit driver produces: "Allowed memory size of xxxx bytes exhausted (tried to allocate yyyy bytes)"
Increasing the memory limits in php.ini has no effect - no matter what the limit is it always claims it's trying to assign more. This error seems related to Kevin Adler's answer on the following thread: [Linux odbc Fatal error: Allowed memory size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286589/linux-odbc-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size) 
Which ties in with IBM's page on [Informix Driver SQLLEN differences](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/398381) between UNIX and Windows Platforms.

I tried setting up a 32-bit release of PHP on the apache server, but the server fails to start when I do so. I'm at a loss on what to try next. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: The error regarding the architecture mismatch is expected, you can't load a 32-bit library from an 64-bit process. Regarding the second error, I downloaded the latest XAMP (7.4.8 / PHP 7.4.8) on my windows box and tried a simple PHP connect test using the CSDK 4.50.FC4 ODBC driver and it appears to work fine. It connects and I can fetch data.  Do you know that PHP is doing (e.g. SQL query) when you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

Per jsagrera's comment, I tried the 4.50.FC4 drivers and that resolved the issue. We were using 3.50.F8, which I learned often produce errors related to the SQLLEN parameter. Thanks jsagrera!